# My npc truffle will not spawn in Terraria

Tags: terraria

[image: game image]

As seen above, I built a surface mushroom biome with several house but the truffle won't spawn. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here are several things you'll want to check on:

- Have you defeated the Wall of Flesh yet? The truffle does not spawn until hardmode is activated.
- Is the house 100% in a surface mushroom biome? If you can clearly hear the biome music, then it is.
- Are you near any corruption or crimson? If so, move the house a little further away from it. The house cannot be within 50 blocks of corruption or crimson.

Comment: I beat the wall of flesh and yes the giant mushrooms are in the backround well I not so surei have a lot of crimson like 33%

Comment: There is a slight chance that he just wont spawn .. You cant do anything about it ... I have 2-3 Times made that experience that he just won't Spawn. So sorry but only a new World is your new Hope :P

Comment: thank u I got rid of some crimson and the truffle spawn thank u

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The Truffle is a hard mode NPC and will only show up once you have constructed a house in an above-ground mushroom biome with Mushroom Grass Seeds, or by using the Clentaminator in a Jungle. If you want to do this but don't want to take up a lot of surface space, a good way to do it is to build a skybridge of mud off of a Floating island, plant Mushroom Grass Seeds, and then wait. (Note that the skybridge must be 2 mud blocks thick, and that the house must meet all of the other normal NPC house requirements.)

[Source](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Truffle)

Comment: so im growing a mushroom biome in the sky there wasent a floating island so I building the biome in the sky will that work

Comment: will it have the mushroom backround no matter how hige I am

Comment: it not working do I have to beat the plantra