# Terraria - NPC problems

Tags: terraria-mobile

Is the truffle and Cyborg NPC in the IOS version? If so, does the truffles house need to be in the mushroom biome?

Answer (score 1):

[Truffle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Truffle) and the [Cyborg](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cyborg) are both available in Terraria Mobile.

The conditions for Truffle to move into a house are the same as those for the PC version, it will only move into a house in a Mushroom Biome. However, it is possible to create and artificial Mushroom Biome on the surface for it to live in.

For more info on creating an above ground Mushroom Biome, take a look at these other questions:

- [How long does the Truffle take to move in after building the mushroom biome?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177934/how-long-does-the-truffle-take-to-move-in-after-building-the-mushroom-biome)
- [My npc truffle will not spawn in Terraria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179314/my-npc-truffle-will-not-spawn-in-terraria)